# Python multiple divs in a row dependent on screen width

Tags: python, html, django

Hello dear stackoverflow community,
as this is my first time ever asking something here please excuse me if I miss any necessary information.

I started to learn Python and the Framework Django by reverse engineering the following website:

thieve.co  as a practice.

Now I am stuck with the following issue:

All my uploaded articles, that are displayed as cards (bootstrap) are automatically arranged below each other. What I actually want to do is that they are displayed in rows, where the number of cards depend on the screen size.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from articles import forms


def article_list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request,'articles/article_list.html',{'articles':articles})

def article_detail(request,slug):
    #return HttpResponse(slug)
    article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request,'articles/article_detail.html',{'article': article})


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateArticle(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateArticle()
    return render(request,'articles/article_create.html',{'form':form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from articles import views

app_name='articles'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.article_list,name="list"),
    path('create/', views.article_create,name="create"),
    path('<slug:slug>',views.article_detail, name="detail"),
]

models.py:

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.png',blank=True,upload_to='../media/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]+'...'
```

models.py:

```
from django import forms
from articles import models

class CreateArticle(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = ['title','body','slug','thumb']
```

article_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}





    <div class="site-header jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbo-head">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>JEDEN TAG DIE BESTEN ENTDECKUNGEN IM NETZ</h3>
        <p class="lead">zusammengestellt von Kreativen</p>
        <p>Werde auch du ein Trenderist!</p>
        <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup'%}" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Trenderist werden</a>

<!--
        <ul class="list-inline" id="filter">
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Latest </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Trenderist Picks </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Trending </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Most Popular </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Price </li>
      </ul>-->
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="content-area-box">


    <div class="content-area" >
            <aside class="sidebar-area" role="complementary">
                <nav class="side-navigation" role="navigation">
                   <ul class="menu">
                     <li class="menu-item">

                     </li>
                     <li class="menu-item">

                     </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Alle Produkte</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Herren</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Damen</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Hauswaren</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Elektronik</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Kinder</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Musik</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Sport & Freizeit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Bürobedarf</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Fotografie</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Spielzeuge</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Baby</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- /.menu-item -->
                   </ul><!-- /.menu -->
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </aside><!-- #secondary -->
            <main class="site-main" role="main">


{% for article in articles %}



                        <div class="articles col-12">

                          <div class="article col-4">
                            <div class="card-group">
                              <div class="card card-size">
                            <a href="{% url 'articles:detail' slug=article.slug %}"><img src="{{article.thumb.url}}" alt="">  </a> <hr>
                            <h6>{{article.title}}</h6><hr>
                            <img src="../static/likes.png" alt="">
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>




              {% endfor %}
              </div>

          </div>


  <!--
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img  src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard" class="img-fluid card">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="lightbox" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        {% for article in articles %}
                        <div class="article">
                          <h6><a href="{% url 'articles:detail' slug=article.slug %}">{{article.title}}</a></h6>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

-->
</main>
</div>
    <footer id="main-footer">

      <div class="row footer">

        <div class="col-sm-4 mehr" >
          <h6>Mehr über Trenderist</h6>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Über Uns</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Karriere bei Trenderist</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Unternehmensverantwortung</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Investoren</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>Hilfe</h6>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Kundenservice</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mein Trenderist</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">AGB</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Impressum</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Über Cookies</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          &copy; 2018 Trenderist<br>
        </div>

    </footer>

{% endblock %}
```

article_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="create-article">
  <h2>Create Article</h2>
  <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'articles:create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
  </form>
</div>
<script src="/static/slugify.js">

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

styles.css:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;   
}

body{
  background-color: gray;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/*.card-group{
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.card .card-size{
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}*/

.content-area {
  display: flex;
  bottom:0;
 }

#content-area-box{
    background-color: gray;
    top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

#jumbo-head{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#filter{
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
}

.site-main {
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;  
}

.sidebar-area {
  margin-top:0;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
}

.side-navigation{
  background-color: gray;
}

.side-navigation.fixed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  width: 290px; 
}

.side-navigation.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  width: 290px; 
}

.side-navigation .menu {
  padding-top: 15px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}

.side-navigation .menu-item {
  position: relative; 
}

.side-navigation .menu-item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  transition: width .3s ease-in; 
}

.side-navigation .menu-item:hover:before {
  width: 100%; 
}

.side-navigation .menu-item a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 50px; 
}

footer {
  margin-top:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

#main-footer{
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#search-width input[type=text]{
  width: 430px !important;
}

#main-footer h6{
  color: #fff;
}

#main-footer a{
  padding-top: 20px;
  color:#fff;
}

#trend-filter{
  background-color: white;
  color:
}

.footer{
  padding-top:20px;
}

.article-detail .article img{
  max-width: 40%;
}

.site-form{
  margin-top:60px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.tester h1{
  text-align:center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}  

.tester{
  padding: 50px;
  color: black;
}

.site-form input, .site-form textarea{
  display:block;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.copyright{
  bottom:0;
  align-items: center;
}

.helptext, helptext ul{
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  display: block;
}

.errorlist li{
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;          
  border: 1px solid #ff5722;
  color: #ff5722;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.errorlist{
  padding: 0;
 }
```

base_layout.html:

```
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Trenderist - JEDEN TAG DIE BESTEN ENTDECKUNGEN IM NETZ</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../templates/base_layout.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #000;">
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="navbar-brand col-sm-4"><img src="{% static 'Logo-weiß.png'%}" alt="trenderistlogo" height="60"> </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>




          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse form-inline" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <div class="nav-item">
                  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    {%csrf_token%}
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-sm-s"  id="search-width" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit">Search</button>

                  </form>
                </div>
              </li>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <div class="btn-group">


                <li class="nav-item">
                  <form class="btn-pill" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button  class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Logout</button>
                  </form>
                </li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'articles:create' %}" class="btn btn-success">Produkt hochladen</a></li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-pill btn-success"  href="{% url 'accounts:login'%}">Login</a></li>

              {% endif %}
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>



          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}



      </body>
    </html>
```

I hope this is all the info you need and I am very thankful for every help I can get.

Comment: Bootstrap will do that for you automatically.

Comment: DOM is Javascript, CSS and HTML not Django exacly... unless you use some lib that do that for you... in your case CSS will do the trick... use class row and col to setup your grid when displaying

Comment: Yes I normally would solve this problem with bootstrap or normal CSS, but somehow I cant figure out why it is not working for this project. I really tried a lot, but maybe there is something that is blocking my CSS commands?? I am just in my second month of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work:

I removed the jumbotron that contained the main part of the website and replaced it with a container-fluid. I then wrapped the for loop in a row div and added some bootstrap cols.

article_list.html:

```
 {% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}





    <div class="site-header jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbo-head">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>JEDEN TAG DIE BESTEN ENTDECKUNGEN IM NETZ</h3>
        <p class="lead">zusammengestellt von Kreativen</p>
        <p>Werde auch du ein Trenderist!</p>
        <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup'%}" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Trenderist werden</a>

<!--
        <ul class="list-inline" id="filter">
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Latest </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Trenderist Picks </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Trending </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Most Popular </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item filter-border"> Price </li>
      </ul>-->
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid" id="content-area-box">


    <div class="content-area" >
            <aside class="sidebar-area" role="complementary">
                <nav class="side-navigation" role="navigation">
                   <ul class="menu">
                     <li class="menu-item">

                     </li>
                     <li class="menu-item">

                     </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Alle Produkte</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Herren</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Damen</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Hauswaren</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Elektronik</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Kinder</a>
                        </li><!-- /.menu-item -->
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Musik</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Sport & Freizeit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Bürobedarf</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Fotografie</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Spielzeuge</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;">Baby</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- /.menu-item -->
                   </ul><!-- /.menu -->
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </aside><!-- #secondary -->
            <main class="site-main" role="main">
              <div class="row">
                {% for article in articles %}
                <div class="article col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                  <a href="{% url 'articles:detail' slug=article.slug %}"><img src="{{article.thumb.url}}" alt="">  </a> <hr>
                  <h6>{{article.title}}</h6><hr>
                  <img src="../static/likes.png" alt="">
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
              </div>






              </div>

          </div>


  <!--
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img  src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard" class="img-fluid card">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="lightbox" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">learn more</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-size">
                      <img src="../static/spoon.jpg" alt="a chalkboard">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        {% for article in articles %}
                        <div class="article">
                          <h6><a href="{% url 'articles:detail' slug=article.slug %}">{{article.title}}</a></h6>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

-->
</main>
</div>
    <footer id="main-footer">

      <div class="row footer">

        <div class="col-sm-4 mehr" >
          <h6>Mehr über Trenderist</h6>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Über Uns</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Karriere bei Trenderist</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Unternehmensverantwortung</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Investoren</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>Hilfe</h6>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Kundenservice</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mein Trenderist</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">AGB</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Impressum</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Über Cookies</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          &copy; 2018 Trenderist<br>
        </div>

    </footer>

{% endblock %}
```